# ERROR ITMS-90685: CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'xamarin.ios.xamarin-framework'

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, app-store-connect, visual-studio-mac

when i am trying to upload the ipa to iTunes Connect i am getting this error:

`ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'xamarin.ios.xamarin-framework' under the iOS application 'appName.iOS.app'."`

Is a solution made using Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin framework, this error occurred after I added a iMessageExtension to app.

I've already seen similar issues but neither one using Xamarin.

• Main App Bundle Identifier format: *com.company.appname*

• Extension App Bundle Identifier format: *com.company.appname.imessageextension*

[Error print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXig4.png)

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I see a similar issue, https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53232, that was fixed a few versions ago. Can you provide your version info?

Comment: Upvoting this since it solved my problem - seems iMessage Extension requires an additional .imessagextension to the usual bundle

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error caused by the duplication of third-party library in your Main App and Extension.

Try to add script as below:

```
cd "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"
if [[ -d "Frameworks"]]; then
rm -fr Frameworks
fi
```

[image]

Comment: when I do this, the app crashes... i saw that inside the framework folder has these two files: xamarin.framework and xamarin-debug.framework, deleting one of them I can upload to itunes, but the extension crashes...